# Changing set_timezone does not always take effect

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have two table

table-1

```
id  date-time
-----------------------
1   2012-12-13 15:20:13
```

table-2

```
id  date-time
-----------------------
1   2012-12-13 15:20:13
```

Now i am selecting the record with mysql `set_timezone` function

Case-1

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
SELECT `date-time` FROM `table-1`;  // 2012-12-13 09:50:13
```

Case-2

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
SELECT `date-time` FROM `table-2`;  // 2012-12-13 15:20:13 ---Not converting to specified timezone
```

In case-1 it's giving converted date-time, but not in Case-2. What would be the issue?

Comment: can you union both tables and see how the date is returning?

Comment: Union also not giving the expected result. I found the issue, in table -1 date-time field datatype is `timestamp` but in table-2 it was `datetime`. Now i changed `datetime` into `timestamp`. Working fine. Thanks for clue.

Comment: Now vote yourself ;) it's acceptable :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table-1

```
id  date-time
 -----------------------
 1   2012-12-13 15:20:13   // datatype->timestamp
```

table-2

```
id  date-time
-----------------------
1   2012-12-13 15:20:13  // datatype->datetime
```

So the issue was with datatype. Now i changed the `datetime` into `timestamp` in table-2. Issue solved.